# Версии пакетов в репозитории Debian обновляются при обнаружении уязвимости?

Tags: debian

Версии пакетов в репозитории Debian обновляются при обнаружении уязвимости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да, в поддерживаемых версиях дистрибутива для пакетов, в которых обнаружены уязвимости, выпускаются новые версии пакетов (не программ!), в которых уязвимости исправлены.

занимается этим [debian security team](https://www.debian.org/security/):

> [Q: How is security handled in Debian?](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#handling)
>
> A: Once the security team receives a notification of an incident, one or more members review it and consider its impact on the stable release of Debian (i.e. if it's vulnerable or not). If our system is vulnerable, we work on a fix for the problem. The package maintainer is contacted as well, if they didn't contact the security team already. Finally, the fix is tested and new packages are prepared, which are then compiled on all stable architectures and uploaded afterwards. After all of that is done, an advisory is published.

для скорейшего получения обновлений к вашей версии дистрибутива имеет смысл не удалять добавляемый по умолчанию в `/etc/apt/sources.list` репозиторий с адресом `security.debian.org`. [для версии `stretch` он выглядит примерно так](https://www.debian.org/security/#keeping-secure):

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Хм, странно. У меня `deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main` и `deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main`.

Comment: C `contrib` и `non-free` всё понятно, но ведь у меня и URL не совпадает.

Comment: Они походу изменили URL: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList